# Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were not closed cleanly

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am running mysql on my EC2 and when I tried to do:
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
I got this:

- Stopping MySQL database server mysqld
- Starting MySQL database server mysqld
- Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were not closed cleanly.

Here is what is in my /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
140406  1:47:27  InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
InnoDB: Error in opening ./ibdata1
140406  1:47:27  InnoDB: Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
140406  1:47:27 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
140406  1:47:27 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
140406  1:47:27 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
140406  1:47:27 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
140406  1:47:27 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
140406  1:47:27 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
140406  1:47:27 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
140406  1:47:27 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140406  1:47:27 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140406  1:47:27 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140406  1:47:27 [ERROR] Aborting

140406  1:47:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140406 01:47:27 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Could someone please tell me what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Did you upgrade MySQL at all? Likely its nothing to worry about.

Comment: My MySQL is currently 5.5, should I upgrade it to 5.6 and the problem will be solved? My currently problem is that it seems like mysql server "has gone away" pretty frequently.

Comment: "Has Gone away" is probably a different issue. Can you provide some more information about your setup and applications?

Comment: Can you share the logs under `/var/log/mysql` when you start and stop mysql?

Comment: I have added more info from the error.log in my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Looks you have a mysql process running. There's a lock on your `./ibdata1` file. it could be that for some reason your `service mysql stop` command is not stopping the process as it may not be finding the `PID` of your mysql server.

Run from the command line:

```
ps -Af | grep mysql
```

Get the PID of your mysql process and then simply:

```
kill -9 <PID of your mysql process>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /var/lib/mysql  
#killall -9 mysqld
#innochecksum -d ibdata1
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 4
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```